# Smart Search within Elastic Search like Google

Tags: database, api, elasticsearch

I want implement smart search like Google in my web site.

So for that we are using approach like below link

http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/how-to-write-a-spelling-corrector-in-csharp/

In that we are using a text file but it is very small collection of words.

It's correcting small and easy words but it fails in complex words.

So please any one assist me to use words database using any api at the place of text file.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options to do the same using Elasticsearch.

1. Use term suggester - Here you can ask Elasticsearch to provide the closest match for a particular term from the terms you have indexed. So this wont complete your text , but rather produce similar alikes from the terms present in the database. So if you search for "railz" , it is capable of providing "rails". You can change the edit_distance parameter to increase the lineancy of this match. It uses the levenshtein distnace algorithm to compute the distance  . 
   URL - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html#search-suggesters-term
2. Auto completion suggester - This suggester is able  to do something like above by changing the fuzzines factor. And also its able to complete your term. So if you search for term "el" , its capable of returning "electrons" , "elasticsearch" and so on. This completion is done on the terms that are already indexed.